# How to actually remove a QGraphicsItem from the screen?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qt4.8

I've got a QGraphicsItem (a map) that has some children (icons on that map). No issues so far.

However, I want to be able to remove the icons from the screen. In order to do this, I tried to just break up the parent-children relationship:

```
foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, displayedIcons) {
    item->setParentItem(NULL);
}
```

In some way, the map and the icons are detached from each other, i.e. when I pan the map, the icons remain at their absolute position on the screen. But the problem is, that the icons are still displayed at all.

Is there anything I am missing in order to actually remove the icons from the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [QGraphicsScene::removeItem()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#removeItem).